# Macros in document (not template) not visible in Word, but VBA-code is in place

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using Win10 and Word 2016.

I have made a Word template with macros (.dotm). When I create a new document (.docm) based on this template all the code (except ThisDocument) is copied from the template to the document.

But these macros are not visible in Word when i reopen the document:
I open the macro-window (alt+F8) and if I in the list at the bottom choose the active document (not 'All...' or the template) none macros are shown. The macrolist is empty.

The shortcuts to the macros doesn't work either.

But if I create a new macro and go back to the macro-window (alt+F8) all the macros are there as they should be. And the shortcuts work.

Why does this happen? And more important: How can I make sure that the macros are visible and the shortcuts work immediately when someone opens the document?

Comment: It was better you could attach the original file so we could try and see what happens, but make sure that your template and created instances have the same object (Document) name. Object names in different languages are shown differently and macros may be disabled if you create an instance. Another thing is to avoid using Active x controls and use shapes instead. Right click on shapes and assign macro. Active x controls get corrupted easily.

Comment: Thank you for your input. 

The code get copied using this code:

    Dim arrAllKode
    arrAllKode = Array([Name of all forms & subs])
    
    For Each Item In arrAllKode
    On Error Resume Next
         Application.OrganizerCopy _
            Source:=ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName, _
            Destination:=ActiveDocument.FullName, _
            Name:=Item, _
            Object:=wdOrganizerObjectProjectItems
    Next Item

Template:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3t2p114NZuhYlc2N2xNb3RjZGs

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the case with all documents based on the template, om whatever computer.

I have found a solution. If I change the attached template to Normal the document's macros appear as they should.

Very strange. But nice to know.

Comment: I guess the design is not in a way to consider carrying codes to the instances, which is kind of reasonable, since the whole point of template is to generate a normal document and not a macro enabled one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the solution was different.  When I went to the Template options (File | Options | Add-Ins then choose Templates from the "Manage" dropdown and click "Go"), my dotm file was listed but there was no tick in the checkbox next to it, so it was not loading automatically.

I checked the box next to the macro file name, restarted Word, and bingo, my macros all reappeared.